# ListBox and Isolated Storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have two questions about Windows Phone Development:

I have two `ListBox` ( `ListBox1`, `ListBox2`)

I save my items in `ListBox1` with isolated storage.

I want to get the selected item from `ListBox1` and put it in the `ListBox2` saving in isolated storage2

When I click on the button to get the selected item in the `Listbox1` and put for the `ListBox2` my application saves all the items that are in `ListBox1` and saves on the  `Listbox2`.

My code:

```
//Isolated Storage

private IsolatedStorageSettings _ListaCompras;
private IsolatedStorageSettings _ListaComprado;
_ListaCompras = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
_ListaComprado = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

//Save Item in ListBox1
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     if (textBoxProduto.Text != string.Empty)
     {
         _ListaCompras.Add(textBoxProduto.Text, "Produto");
         _ListaCompras.Save();
         salvarLista();
         contador();
     }
     else MessageBox.Show("Informe o Produto"); 
 } 

 //Get the Selected item for ListBox1 and put the ListBox2

 private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     if ((listBoxComprar.Items.Count <= 0) || (this.listBoxComprar.SelectedIndex == -1))
     MessageBox.Show("Selecione um item na lista de pendentes");
     else
     {
       _ListaComprado.Add(listBoxComprar.SelectedItem.ToString(), "ProdutoComprado");
       _ListaComprado.Save();
       salvarLista2();
     }
  }

//BIND KEYS

  public void salvarLista() 
  {
       listBoxComprar.Items.Clear();
       foreach (string key in _ListaCompras.Keys)
       {
           this.listBoxComprar.Items.Add(key);
       }
       textBoxProduto.Text = "";
   }
   public void salvarLista2()
   {
       listBoxComprado.Items.Clear();
       foreach (string key2 in _ListaComprado.Keys)
       {
            this.listBoxComprado.Items.Add(key2);       
       }
   }
```

Comment: I can't understand the question.  You're trying to have the selected item from lb1 save to isolated storage?  What's the end thing you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear but I think I figured it out. 
You are saving the value as key and a string as value in the applicationsettings. This should be the other way around, the string (Produto and ProdutoComprado) as keys and the values as values.

I think you have the Add(key, value) statement mixed up. [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings.add%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

So

```
_ListaCompras.Add(textBoxProduto.Text, "Produto");
```

should be:

```
_ListaCompras.Add("Produto", textBoxProduto.Text);
```

and

```
_ListaComprado.Add(listBoxComprar.SelectedItem.ToString(), "ProdutoComprado");
```

should be:

```
_ListaComprado.Add("ProdutoComprado", listBoxComprar.SelectedItem.ToString());
```